# How do I remove the Recycle Bin from the taskbar notification area?

Tags: windows, icons, recycle-bin

I'm running windows 8, and I suddenly have a recycle bin icon on the right side of the taskbar to the left of the arrow icon in the notification area.  How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Never seen that one.. Please provide a screenshot of what you're speaking of.

Comment: By right clicking the Task Bar you will get a list of option. Towards the top of the options given you should see the option **Toolbars** . If you click the Toolbar option do you see another drop down list. Do you see the option Recycling Bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Actual Window Manager (or some other manager from Actual)?  In the most recent update an option was added (or auto enabled?) that shows the Recycle Bin icon on the taskbar.  Go into the Actual settings, Taskbar section and disable it.